# What causes yellowing of clear finish under vinyl placemats?

Tags: tabletop, finish-selection

I had a new table top made of solid wood as my old one was veneer that was wrecked by scratches & white marks by hot pads not being used. So I asked for a strong protective clear coating so wood wouldn't easily get wrecked by guests. He suggested a clear 'bar coating' (several layers to make it last).  I used the same vinyl placemats used on my old tabletop but within month noticed underneath them the finish is yellowing!! Chemical reaction? Wrong product finish? Help!

Comment: Is epoxy resin what was meant by "bar coating?" Also, can you [edit] your post to include pictures?

Comment: Normal varnish or lacquer is enough for home tables  ;) 'bar coating' is for commercial use and abuse - careless use, puddles ignored, cleaned multiple times each day.

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackExchange. Yes please add pics so we can get a look at what's happened. Although contamination of the coating seems a possibility, especially if the vinyl placemats are flexible (as this means they include plasticisers, which are notorious for migrating out of the original material) there is a chance the wood has changed colour and not the coating. Although the second seems very unlikely given the short timeframe only one month seems very short for the other explanation too. How much light does the table see, is it near a window where it gets direct sunlight part of the day?

Comment: As Graphus pointed out, depending on the species and the amount of sunlight it is subjected to, it could be that the wood around the mats is darkening.  I've seen black cherry do that in pretty short order as a window sill with a potted plant on it, a few weeks and you could already see the difference.  keeping it empty helped it even out and after awhile it slowed down getting darker and we could put stuff on it again.  (South facing window).  Pics would definitely help figure this out.

Comment: @bowlturner, \*doh* stupidly cherry didn't even occur to me (no idea why!) and that's famous for how quickly the colour can change if there's enough light. A month near a bright window could do it.

Comment: VTC for lack of followup on requested information.